# UIGetScreenImage() in Landscape?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I use the following code to get a screenshot of the screen and save it to the photo albums.

```
 CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
        UIImage *screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenimage, nil, nil), nil);
```

This works great but if my app is in landscape mode the saved image does not come out right. (in needs a 90 degree turn). What do  i need to do?

Comment: Note that UIGetScreenImage() has been made private by Apple again, and your application will be rejected if it uses this function: http://www.drahtwerk.biz/EN/Blog.aspx/iOS-4-updates-delayed/?newsID=45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for either

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
(and possibly more orientations)
```

Then do the appropriate transformations to the image.

This can be done in several ways, this one doesn't take a lot of code:

```
/// click action saves orientation & picture:
-(void)screenshot
{
    self.orientationWhenPicked = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);
}

/// somewhere else we are called for the image
-(UIImage*)getScreenshot
{
    UIDeviceOrientation useOrientation = self.orientationWhenPicked;
    UIImage *img = self.image;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480.0f, 320.0f));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if ( useOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
            CGContextRotateCTM (context, M_PI/2.0f);
            [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, -480.0f)];
    } else {
            CGContextRotateCTM (context, -M_PI/2.0f);
            [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-320.0f, 0.0f)];
    }
    UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return ret;
}
```

I modified it a little before posting to make it self-contained, but it should work with a little effort (e.g. create `self.image` etc). You may just blend them into one function.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you please explain what this line does:             [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-320.0f, 0.0f)];

And what it has to do with the rotation?

Thanks in advance,
-David

Comment: That's the line that puts the original image in the new image context. The `(-320,0)` coordinates make sure you cover the entire screen after rotation around (0,0).

Comment: what's self.image in both functions for? And why is getScreenshot a void method?

Comment: @indiekiduk: `self.image` is a property that stores the image. `-getScreenshot` should of course return `UIImage*`, thanks for noting.